# sheet inside ForEach doesn't loop over id's

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Each link has an id, the output I get when I click on the button is the wrong id, it repeats the first id on the first 4 buttons and then the others are random.

```
struct PricesList: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var isSheetPresented = false
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, spacing: 15, content:  {
                    ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.id) { item in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
                            Button(action: {
                                self.isSheetPresented.toggle()
                            }, label: {
                                Image(item.imageUrl)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .padding(10)
                            }).sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented, content: {
                                WebView(url: item.link)
                            })
                            
                        }//:VSTACK
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(12))
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    }//: LOOP FOR EACH
                }).padding(5)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    viewModel.loadData()
                    viewModel.postData()
                })
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }//: NAVIGATION VIEW
    } //: BODY
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `sheet` for each item in your list, and all of them are getting `isSheetPresented` value. Which one will be displayed is undefined

Instead you need to store `selectedItem` and pass it to single `sheet`, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    @State var selectedItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, spacing: 15, content:  {
                    ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.id) { item in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
                            Button(action: {
                                selectedItem = item
                            }, label: {
                                Image(item.imageUrl)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .padding(10)
                            })

                        }//:VSTACK
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(12))
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    }//: LOOP FOR EACH
                }).padding(5)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    viewModel.loadData()
                    viewModel.postData()
                })
                .sheet(item: $selectedItem, content: { selectedItem in
                    WebView(url: selectedItem.link)
                })
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }//: NAVIGATION VIEW
    } //: BODY
}
```

Comment: Hi! I get two errors, "Cannot find type 'Item' in scope" on `@State var selectedItem: Item?` and "Cannot find '$selectedItem' in scope" on the .sheet

Comment: @RafaelaSantos I used `Item` because I don't know actual class of your `viewModel.items`, just replace it with your own

Comment: @RafaelaSantos have you been able to do it? You need to open your `ViewModel` declaration, check out on `@Published var items: [*YourItemClass*]` and replace `Item` in my code with `*YourItemClass*`

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out, can you take a look? This is my swiftUI file, it's parsing the json data from a npoint link https://github.com/rafaela466/iosTest/blob/main/testing

Comment: @RafaelaSantos your `PrecosLista` needs to be `Identifiable` to use it in sheet. You already have `id`, so the only left is adding conformance to protocol, like this: `struct PrecosLista: Decodable, Identifiable {`